# C++: Hacky parameter pattern with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, variadic-functions

Is it possible to use C++ variadic arguments to define a function that allows exactly the following calls:

```
f(int, char)
f(int, char, char)
f(int, char, char, int)
f(int, char, char, int, char)
...
```

Where every nth argument is a `char` if n is a prime number, and otherwise it is an `int`. The function can only be called in this way; it does not compile with other parameter patterns (e.g. `f(2, 2)` is an error, but `f(2, '2')` is ok).

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.  It might also not be a bad idea to explain a possible use-case.

Comment: you know that a `f(int,char)` can be called as `f(2,2)` without error and are seeking for a way to make it an error or is it sufficient to get the signature right?

Comment: Actually, there is no use-case for this. I just wanted to know if it is possible;-) Thanks for the hint with the auto-casting; I do not care about the used types in the signature, but more about how to create this pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming:

```
constexpr bool is_prime(size_t);
```

Then something like this:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct typelist;

template <size_t... Is>
constexpr auto expected(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    -> typelist<std::conditional_t<is_prime(Is+1), char, int>...>;

template <typename... Ts,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<
        typelist<Ts...>,
        decltype(expected(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}))
        >::value, int> = 0>
auto f(Ts... ts);
```

Comment: Awesome! Very laconic and elegant.

Comment: but isnt `2` a valid `char` and `f(int,char)` can be called without error as `f(2,2)` ? (I am refering to "it does not compile with other parameter patterns (e.g. `f(2, 2)` is an error, but `f(2, '2')` is ok).")

Comment: @user463035818 valid concern, but probably best addressed at OP. I wonder about that too.

Comment: @user463035818 Try `static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(2), char>);`

Comment: @IgorR. I know that `2` is not a `char`, I just wonder how to fullfill the requirement stated by OP

Comment: @user463035818 I got it: it's pure template deduction, then the types are matched exactly in the SFINAE test. No implicit conversions are considered.

Comment: @user463035818 Take a look at the following: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Pyrn50SLSrG0X6qj